# struts2 convention plugin dependency

Tags: java, dependency-management, struts2-convention-plugin

I have a project which was running fine. I wanted to try the annotations in struts 2 so i added the convention plugin jar(2.3.14.2) to my WEB-INF/lib folder along with the other struts2 jars. Upon restarting my tomcat server within eclipse, i get a

`SEVERE: Error filterStart` with 
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor.`

So i added an `asm-all-4.1.jar` upon which i get the same error but this time with:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/objectweb/asm/commons/EmptyVisitor.`

I looked at the documentation page for the plugin but it does not even mention this asm dependency.
I've also tried including the jars in tomcat's classpath but that was of no use either. Help!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. Instead I added the asm jars from the struts2 library (asm-3.3, commons and tree) and that seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Please consider using a tool to manage your project's dependencies. Doing so manually leaves you open to lots of dependency- and dependency-version-related errors, like this one.